# Commerce Kickstart is saving a transaction as both incompleted & successful

Tags: commerce

I have a site running Commerce Kickstart (Drupal 7.23, Kickstart 7.x-2.9)
I've noticed that some of the transactions are registered twice: one as not completed & the other one, as successful.
It's not so common, but it happens. I'm thinking that some users might have taken a long time to complete their order & Drupal registered it as checked out only (not completed yet), when they finally paid the order, it's was saved as a new order. I'm still not sure if this is the case or something else.
Has anyone experienced this issue & what have you done?

Comment: what payment method are you using ?

Comment: regardless of the question, if you are actually running a Drupal site with a version 7.23, you need to update it immediately to secure against a number of security vulnerabilities found, include https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2014-005